# oracle database avoid duplicate state

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

I tried looking this up, but since I have no clue what I am looking for my search queries are returning me nothing.

Essentially I have a table that looks like the following:

```
Non-Unique-Id | ... | ... | ... | Historical_flag
1             | ... | ... | ... | 0
1             | ... | ... | ... | 1
1             | ... | ... | ... | 1
2             | ... | ... | ... | 0
```

I need a way for oracle to stop me if I try to insert into the database or modify a record where there is more than one record that has Historical_flag=0 with a specific non-unique-id

So looking at the data I provided above, its all good. There is more than one record that has historical=0, but they do not share a non-unique-id, so thats cool. The problem arises where someone tries to insert into the db.

An example of what I am trying to simulate, with the above table in mind is

```
Insert into my_table (non-unique-id, historical_flag) values (1, 0)
> Error: Cannot insert due to rule x (...or you know..any error really....)
```

The problem is, its not really that I want a unique combination, because as you can see, we can have multiple entries where historical_flag=1... but only one where its = 0.

Any tips as to how to solve this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

PS: Let me know if there is any additional data I should provide!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in Oracle using a functional unique index.  The key is to make the other values `NULL`, so uniqueness is not checked.

```
create unique index idx_mytable_id_flag on mytable
  (case when historical_flag = 0 then id end);
```

EDIT: corrected

Comment: What do you mean by "Make the other values NULL"? Is this not possible if I use 1 and 0? I NEED to make it 1 and null or 0 and null? IS there some way I can say "Hey, its a 1, but in the index, treat 1 as null"..just like a decode within the index?

Comment: Yes, that is what the above code does.  It is called a function-based index.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, you have great response time and great answers. I will give it a try tomorrow as it is the end of the day where I am right now, but it seems to be exactly what I need!

Comment: Hey Gordon, I just gave this a try and it is giving me a problem with duplicate keys found. I am not sure if it ignores null duplicates...

Comment: Just needed a slight correction. We don't need to index id's on rows that have historical_flag = 1.